# USA National Power Grid Regions

Tags: data-request, geospatial, energy

I would like the polygons for the USA Western, Eastern and Texas Interconnects as well as their sub-regions.  These are illustrated [here](http://www.earthlyissues.com/uspower.htm).

[image]

Any ideas where I can find shape files for these?

I don't strictly need the power lines; just the regions. If major power lines are included I would like them to be in a different layer from the region polygon so they can be removed. I am hoping that these polygons would not require a license/subscription since they are not too detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may take some digging through the EIA-861 dataset (http://www.eia.gov/electricity/data/eia861/). It contains a dozen or so tables, but the ones you may be able to piece together are:

- Service Territory – This file, compiled from data collected on the Form EIA-861 and Form 861S, contains the names of the counties, by state, in which the respondent has equipment for the distribution of electricity to ultimate consumers.
- Utility Data (2007 forward) – This file, compiled from data collected on Form EIA-861 only, contains information on the types of activities each utility engages in, the NERC regions of operation, whether the utility generates power, whether it operates alternative-fueled vehicles, and, beginning in 2010, the ISO or RTO region in which the entity conducts operations.
- Balancing Authority – This file, compiled from data collected on both Forms EIA-861 and EIA-861S, contains information on Balancing Authorities.

You will have to deal with the fact of utilities operating in multiple counties and NERC territories by making some simplifying assumptions.

Using these tables you may be able to calculate which counties are in which NERC regions. Shapefiles for counties are easier to come by either from the census (https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html) or in the software package of your choosing.

I am not sure whether this will work, but it may be a start. When I was doing an analysis involving utilities at the county level it suited my needs, but your request is obviously different. If I find myself tackling this exact problem in my research I will try to come back and post code.

Comment: This could prove a useful set of base data (+1).  It requires a bit of work to get the polygons out. I am giving it a go as well.

Answer (score 3):

The EIA has a new page with a clickable US-electric-grid map

[image]

In the source code, you can find the shape details of the demand map in the source code.

I've put the source code for the shapes of the 13 individuals regions into a [shared zipped folder](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7652121/US-grid-shapes.zip). I assume the format is something similar to SVG.

Here's a sample of the SW Region data:

```
<path cursor="pointer" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="4" stroke="#513c7a" fill-opacity="1" fill="#e6eaf5" data-code="REG-SW" d="M95.968,427.651l0.636,-0.551l0.294,-0.114l1.169,-1.14l2.271,-0.039l0.404,0.403l1.426,-0.014l0.086,7.187l-6.286,-5.731ZM102.865,433.941l1.165,-0.02l0.011,0.885l0.407,0.395l8.46,-0.145l0.306,0.297l13.598,-0.224l0.307,0.299l6.795,-0.117l0.393,-0.405l-0.032,-2.554l3.393,0.004l0.4,-0.398l0.003,-4.384l13.513,0.001l0.4,-0.4l0.0,-3.514l0.697,-0.043l0.365,-0.399l-0.003,-8.09l12.952,-0.001l-0.045,30.645l0.035,2.035l0.398,0.396l55.278,-0.075l0.491,0.122l55.77,-0.042l0.307,0.15l39.42,-0.022l20.419,-0.129l-0.005,8.914l-0.213,-0.0l-0.401,0.4l0.003,18.294l-4.883,0.18l-0.385,0.409l-0.0,2.083l-3.206,0.003l-0.0,-0.217l-0.399,-0.4l-1.124,-0.003l-3.816,-7.061l-0.548,-0.159l-0.602,0.338l-3.672,-0.002l-0.411,0.389l0.179,0.189l0.039,1.547l0.413,0.39l0.63,-0.021l0.017,0.678l-0.585,0.019l-0.387,0.41l0.061,2.403l-1.876,0.062l-0.387,0.41l0.025,0.975l-0.74,0.024l-0.387,0.41l0.061,2.386l0.413,0.39l0.527,-0.017l0.037,1.431l-1.876,0.062l-0.275,0.122l-1.448,1.505l-1.387,0.046l-0.387,0.41l0.09,3.494l-1.101,0.036l-0.387,0.41l0.139,5.396l-0.89,0.029l-0.387,0.41l0.095,4.032l0.388,0.4l8.152,0.238l-0.002,0.306l0.399,0.402l0.794,0.001l0.21,0.212l0.702,0.001l-0.051,9.003l-0.293,-0.0l-0.401,0.397l-0.008,1.213l-0.464,0.397l-0.004,0.627l-0.464,0.397l-0.011,1.723l-2.058,0.201l-1.903,0.03l-0.393,0.391l-0.046,2.161l-0.317,2.853l-0.471,-0.001l-0.401,0.397l-0.01,1.563l-0.362,-0.0l-0.401,0.397l-0.005,0.843l-1.398,-0.002l-0.4,0.405l0.006,1.007l0.126,0.283l1.277,1.264l-0.005,0.769l0.399,0.403l0.902,0.001l-0.011,1.763l0.399,0.403l0.902,0.001l-0.007,1.176l0.399,0.403l1.274,0.002l-0.005,0.766l0.413,0.402l1.826,-0.043l-0.092,4.219l0.407,0.409l0.262,-0.004l-0.019,0.875l0.407,0.409l1.314,-0.022l-0.085,3.91l-27.699,-0.042l-0.401,0.404l0.034,4.393l0.427,0.395l0.674,-0.045l3.106,2.709l0.087,1.724l0.425,0.379l0.137,-0.009l0.031,0.629l0.501,0.374l0.027,0.54l0.501,0.375l0.05,1.012l0.895,0.764l3.235,-0.2l0.04,1.011l0.95,0.704l0.855,-0.051l0.007,0.155l0.423,0.381l0.547,-0.032l0.4,0.361l1.004,-0.059l0.98,0.771l1.625,-0.092l0.0,0.169l0.422,0.399l1.276,-0.071l0.38,0.345l0.659,-0.036l0.042,1.061l-0.231,0.013l-0.378,0.415l0.022,0.549l-0.117,-0.106l-0.946,0.053l-0.337,-0.33l-0.482,-0.001l-0.426,-0.478l-1.061,0.061l-0.424,-0.419l-1.091,0.063l-0.347,-0.376l-0.024,-0.554l-0.423,-0.382l-1.003,0.06l-0.427,-0.447l-1.737,0.105l-0.375,0.437l-1.074,0.066l-0.375,0.418l0.006,0.137l-0.46,0.424l0.022,0.461l-0.508,-0.048l-0.239,-0.403l-0.087,-0.596l-0.426,-0.686l-0.531,-0.341l-0.276,-0.32l-0.863,-0.34l-0.497,-0.493l-0.428,-0.079l-0.08,-0.361l-1.384,-1.727l-0.476,-0.223l-0.149,-0.232l-0.466,-0.161l-0.21,-0.745l-1.102,-0.704l-1.031,-0.1l-0.422,-0.39l-0.444,-0.101l-0.66,-0.55l-0.364,-0.137l-0.602,-1.331l-0.466,-0.344l-0.326,-0.953l-0.718,-1.401l-0.389,-0.38l-0.261,-0.461l-1.101,-0.601l-0.354,-0.034l-0.375,0.214l-0.683,-0.59l-26.164,0.006l-0.4,0.401l-0.003,7.829l-44.168,0.021l-23.767,-8.811l-34.019,-12.351l-0.022,-0.3l0.243,-0.661l-0.179,-0.376l0.016,-0.443l0.766,-0.885l0.541,-1.214l1.233,0.187l0.091,-0.112l0.408,-0.007l0.399,-0.272l0.262,-0.003l0.193,-0.135l0.391,-0.452l-0.072,-0.459l0.875,-0.853l0.154,-0.779l0.026,-0.787l-0.224,-0.341l0.104,-0.299l-0.038,-0.399l-0.359,-0.388l-0.111,-0.49l-0.222,-0.373l-0.349,-0.24l-0.809,-0.121l-0.675,0.182l-0.358,-0.366l-0.294,0.029l-0.187,-0.448l-0.242,-0.264l0.405,-0.963l0.094,-1.237l-0.125,-0.345l0.146,-0.374l-0.223,-0.488l-0.553,-0.283l0.237,-0.322l0.135,-0.543l-0.187,-0.805l0.346,-0.528l-0.332,-0.345l-1.224,-0.203l1.276,-1.453l0.457,-2.205l0.218,-0.174l0.252,-0.536l-0.41,-4.64l1.594,-2.164l0.322,-2.243l3.2,0.246l0.036,0.235l0.559,-0.087l0.009,-0.143l0.385,-0.33l-0.368,-0.429l-7.998,-0.614l0.169,-2.292l0.86,-3.576l0.869,0.062l0.318,-0.302l2.32,0.17l0.309,-0.262l1.153,0.102l0.395,-0.573l-0.301,-0.292l0.043,-0.307l-0.261,-0.431l-0.533,-1.718l-1.296,-1.072l-0.484,-1.228l-0.72,-0.663l0.093,-1.118l-0.08,-0.498l0.091,-0.412l-0.084,-0.423l-15.592,-15.29l-13.404,-12.825l-15.764,-14.82l-10.068,-9.277ZM159.996,503.669l0.343,0.45l0.45,-0.343l0.017,-0.128l-0.34,-0.45l-0.452,0.336l-0.018,0.134ZM159.6,505.303l-0.085,0.202l0.548,0.209l0.423,-0.467l0.106,-0.556l-0.556,-0.106l-0.127,0.215l-0.085,-0.038l-0.223,0.541ZM158.606,513.564l0.35,0.444l0.448,-0.377l-0.35,-0.445l-0.448,0.377ZM159.316,511.776l-0.517,-0.26l-0.224,0.562l0.511,0.242l0.231,-0.544ZM157.874,482.607l0.038,0.276l0.451,0.342l0.342,-0.451l-0.045,-0.326l-0.451,-0.342l-0.335,0.501ZM156.818,484.69l0.234,0.059l0.055,0.152l0.216,0.114l-0.06,0.576l0.564,0.046l0.156,-0.133l0.046,-0.564l-0.089,-0.007l-0.081,-0.517l-0.163,-0.104l0.192,-0.458l-0.522,-0.219l-0.156,0.064l-0.159,0.379l-0.157,-0.039l-0.138,0.549l0.061,0.102Z"></path>
```

If someone can convert these to proper shapefile or geojson format, I'd appreciate if you'd edit this answer, or put a link in the comments and I'll add it.

---

[image]